# Display emulator no longer working with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display, headless

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19 to 20.04.
I was using TeamViewer to connect to my box in lieu of the display.
The box was running headless with [display emulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FB8GJ1Z)

After the upgrade, TeamViewer sees the box but is not connecting or displaying the remote host.
After I connected a monitor to the box, TeamViewer is able to connect and show the remote screen.

I have searched the internet awhile now, but could not find anything useful.  Please help.

Comment: It's because the box does not allow me to see things without logging in.  Once I login the emulator works fine.  Need to recall what I've done to work around this.

Comment: Have you tried to set it up to [run as a startup service with systemd](https://www.howtogeek.com/687970/how-to-run-a-linux-program-at-startup-with-systemd/)? It reads like it is started after login and not on boot.

Comment: Actually, the computer is visible to Teamviewer before logging in.  So, it's definitely running on startup.  It appears to be a Teamviewer problem after I upgraded.  Other people have complained https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/107003/tv-15-9-5

Comment: Switched to VNC and it all works now!

Comment: That works. I'm a huge x11vnc fan with RealVNC as my viewer.